# Comment traduire "bottom up" et "top down"

Tags: vocabulaire

Quel est le meilleur moyen d'exprimer les notions de "bottom up" (décision qui est construite à partir de la base) et "top down" (décision qui vient du sommet de la hiérarchie)?  J'ai trouvé "de bas en haut" ou "de haut en bas" comme traduction, mais je ne trouve pas ça très parlant en français.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Je propose les termes «ascendante» et «descendante».

Ces termes et semblent s'appliquer tant dans le domaine de la gestion que dans celui de la communication. Le court article Wikipédien [Approches ascendante et descendante](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approches_ascendante_et_descendante) traite du sujet.

Answer (score 3):

Pour une décision qui vient du sommet de la hiérarchie on dirait "une décision qui vient d'en haut".

Une alternative (qui a l'avantage, en plus, d'être à la mode), est de parler d'un mode de décision "vertical" pour "top down" (les ordres viennent d'en haut) et "horizontal" quand c'est censé être "bottom up".

Je ne connais pas vraiment d'expression qui fait le miroir avec "une décision qui vient d'en haut". Parler de décision qui "vient d'en bas" me paraît pousser un peu loin le bouchon. À la limite une périphrase, "construite avec la base" comme dans la question. Mais ce n'est pas très joli.

Comment: venu d'en haut. venu d'en bas. horizontal ne marche pas.

Comment: @Lambie Je ne comprends pas ce commentaire. Est-ce que c'est parce que "bottom up" fait référence à quelque chose de vertical, alors qu'en français on parle d'horizontalité ? Traduire les expressions littéralement n'a pas beaucoup d'intérêt.

Comment: Le trait sémantique horizontal ne se trouve pas dans bottom up. Cela n'a rien à voir avec quoi que ce soit d'horizontal. Mon commentaire était clair.

Comment: @Lambie Clair mais faux... On traduit "it's raining cats and dogs" par "il pleut comme vache qui pisse", où sont les vaches dans l'expression anglaise ? Encore une fois, on ne traduit pas les expressions littéralement, sinon on fait des contresens grossiers.

Comment: Bottom up veut dire du BAS vers le HAUT. Donc, rien de horizontal. Décision de la base (bottom) vers le haut. Les deux movements (bottom up et top down) sont verticaux, dans des directions opposées. ↑ ↓ Voilà.

Comment: @Lambie Et "it's raining cats and dogs" veut dire "il pleut des CHATS et des CHIENS", alors pourquoi est-ce qu'on parle de vache en français? Moi aussi je sais utiliser les majuscules.

Comment: Non, it's raining cats and dogs veut dire: Il pleut à verse. Les deux petits mots en majuscules c'était pour souligner....no big deal, Pour information, je suis traductrice (vers l'anglais) par formation et par expérience (professionnelle).

Comment: @Lambie Et donc ? D'une part cela signifie que tu es experte de l'anglais, pas du français. D'autre part, quand je vois la qualité de certaines traductions professionnelles, je me dis que cet argument d'autorité n'a pas une valeur très importante. Mais passons.

Comment: L'horizontalité arrive quand on se rend compte qu'une base est en général plus large que le sommet. Et en tant que traductrice, j'espère que tu es au courant que ce qui compte est d'employer des expressions idiomatiques qui ont le sens que le texte original veut faire passer, pas des traductions littérales.

Answer (score 2):

That’s a good question. There is no exact equivalent, to the point that you often hear people directly use the English,  “un modèle top down, bottom up (pronouced "toppe-daoune", "botome-eup"), in jargony professional lingo.

I would probably use descendant/ascendant, but in brackets, I’d specify what I mean with the English expression in italics or between inverted comas.

Bottom up change can translate as : changement venu de la base, changement d’origine citoyenne ou locale.

Top down decision can be: décision qui vient d’en haut, although that covers the fact it’s from the top, but not that it’s going down that much...

I think it will depend on WHAT is top-down/ bottom up: is it progress? Is it a decision? Evolution? Problems? You may find a proper but different translation for each...

Comment: ascendent and descendent is not the translation here ever. You have found the equivalent meanings though. What matters is equivalent meaning, not "equivalence". Top down doesn't mean going down. It means just what you said: venu de la base, venu d'en haut.

Answer (score 1):

Bien qu'**ascendant** et **descendant** traduisent très bien ***bottom up*** et ***top down***, je trouve que dans le cas précis de la question, « **décision ascendante** » et « **décision ascendante** » sont peu compréhensibles et d'ailleurs inconnus de google books :

[image]

On pourra plutôt opposer « **décision hiérarchique** » et « **[décision collégiale](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=alt&srchtxt=DECISION%20COLLEGIALE)** » comme le graphique suivant, extrait de de la page http://organizationalphysics.com/2016/10/13/top-down-vs-bottom-up-hierarchy-or-how-to-build-a-self-managed-organization/ le suggère :

[image]

Une décision hiérarchique est prise par un individu qui en a la prérogative (et qui n'est pas forcément au sommet de la hiérarchie). Elle ne peut pas être contestée par les personnes situées en dessous de lui dans la hiérarchie. Ça correspond bien à *top-down*.

Une décision collégiale est prise par un groupe (donc forcément avec un mécanisme de gestion des conflit, souvent un vote à la majorité simple) et s'impose à tous. Elle est prise par un groupe plus ou moins restreint d'individus (le [collège](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/coll%C3%A8ge)) parfois situés en haut de la hiérarchie. Si l'on souhaite indiquer que la décision a été prise par un ensemble plus large de participants, on peut alors opposer :

- **décision unilatérale hiérarchique**  (*top-down*)

à

- **décision collective consensuelle** (bottom-up).

Comment: Je ne pense pas que "décision collégiale" soit adapté. "Collégial" signifie que la décision a été prise par un groupe de personnes plutôt que par une seule personne. Par exemple, les décisions d'un conseil d'administration sont collégiales. On ne peut pas pour autant dire qu'elles "viennent d'en bas".

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Je comprends l'objection mais dans la vrai vie, une décision qui vient d'en bas est forcément consensuelle, elle est donc aussi collégiale.

Comment: 1. Épargne-moi ce ton paternaliste. 2. Tu n'as visiblement pas compris l'objection. Une décision "collégiale" peut aussi bien venir "d'en haut" que "d'en bas". J'ai donné l'exemple d'un conseil d'administration. Ça n'a donc aucun sens de recommander cette expression pour distinguer une décision qui vient d'en bas et pas d'en haut, vu qu'une décision collégiale peut très bien venir d'en haut.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Désolé si tu perçois un ton paternaliste. J'ai bien compris qu'une décision collégiale ne vient pas forcément du bas de la hiérarchie. Je pense quand même que cette expression correspond à *bottom-up* dans le cas précis de la question mais ce n'est qu'une opinion que je n'impose à personne.

Comment: Ce n'est pas une question d'opinion. "Une décision collégiale fut prise de changer la couleur du logo de l'entreprise." Est-ce que dans cette phrase on arrive à dire si c'est venu d'en haut (le conseil d'administration par exemple...), ou d'en bas ? Non.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi J'ai ajouté *décision collective / consensuelle* à ma réponse pour tenter de prendre en compte ton objection qui est pertinente.

Comment: collégiale et collectif simplement n'ont rien à voir avec bottom up/down. Une décison peut passer d'un PDG aux directeurs, ensuites elle passe aux sous-directeurs et  aux responsables et aux pauvres c**s aux charbon. C'est top down et cela n'a rien de collégial ni de collectif. Dans le sens que tous participent (bottom up), cela serait une décision de la base vers le haut.

Comment: @Lambie Oui, c'est ce que j'ai écrit. *Top down* n'a rien de collégial ou de collectif, c'est même le contraire. *Bottom up*, c'est la base qui arrive à un consensus et prend la décision, donc la collectivité (l'ensemble des personnes) prend une décision qui s'impose à tout le monde.

Comment: Ok, d'accord, mais je ne suis pas d'accord avec la traduction, c'est trop lourd.